# node-red Editor: The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading

Tags: node-red

Tried installing node-red On both Linux and Windows.
It works fine using a browser on localhost or a machine on the same subnet.
From another subnet it won't work. No traffic is blocked by the firewall.
A test with a local installed httpd server works fine.

Comment: My bad, running IIS on port 1880 aks does not work. Then it has nothing to do with node-red. For referecnce I wil post the solution here when I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

My Bad, running a webserver op port 1880 the connection was reset.
Node-red is not the problem.
Further inspection of the firewall revealed the page is blocked by a data filtering rule because of: 'Scalable Vector Graphics SVG File'